# Android FileNotFoundException, why?

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I want to touch a file in the device. The file name is /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf.
I can see it with adb shell.
If I try to open it with the code below, I get a FileNotFoundException. Why???

```
private void touchFile(String fileName) {

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try {
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        bufferedWriter.append(' ');
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can we see the stack trace that you're printing?

Comment: 04-04 23:19:19.196: W/System.err(1221): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Yes it is a permission denied, but I am supposed to be root on this machine.

Answer (score 1):

the path `/data/misc/` is only accessible with root permission. That's probably why you are getting this exception.

Comment: You are right, but the machine is rooted, in fact I want to manage the changes in Wifi settings with a FileObserver.

Comment: I see. check in /system/etc/wifi ?

Comment: It seems the answer is Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su") to run the process as root. I give it a try and let you know.